# We have a report that prints details for Pending Change Orders for jobs.

Tags: crystal-reports, report

We need the total to subtract the amount if there is a PCO Status "rejected". How do we do this?

The report itself prints details of each pending change order, then totals those pending change orders at the end. However, sometimes the pending change order is rejected, leaving it Status 'R', which we would not want included in the total. We want to make a formula, but are not entirely sure how to do this successfully.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each change order is a row in your report, you can sum those that do not have a status of rejected by creating a formula that simply returns 0 for those rows:

`if isnull({PCO.Status}) or not({PCO.status}="rejected") then {PCO.NumberToSum} else 0`

Then you just need to insert a `sum()` summary into your report on this new formula field.

Comment: When I create the formula it says it cannot be summarized. This is the formula I created based on your previous information

IF isnull({PMOI.Status}) or not({PMOI.Status}="3")
THEN {@PrintPendAmtPCO}
ELSE
0

Comment: What is the `{@PrintPendAmtPCO}` formula? There may be something in there that is preventing the summarization.

Comment: @PrintPendAmtACO is WhilePrintingRecords;
NumberVar PCOPendAmt;PCOPendAmt

I did not create this formula. The software company did. So I don't know why it was done this way or anything.

Comment: The report is keeping track of the running total manually via a variable for whatever reason, which usually means there is something slightly more complicated going on. Somewhere in the report you'll have a formula that is updating the `PCOPendAmt` variable... if you can find it and post what code is in it along with what section of the report, we might be able to workaround it.

Answer (score -1):

one way would be take the total sum in one variable and rejected sum in another variable and subtract the both and print final result.

```
//For Rejected        
Local Numbervar a;
If (Status='R') Then a:=sum(Total);

//Total with rejected
Sum(Total);

//For total without rejected
Sum(Total)-a;
```

Comment: -1 for overly-complicated and untested answer (you will get an error on the `Local Nubervar a` line.

Comment: I don't think it is a **overly complicated**... Is there any rule that answer should be simple?... This is my idea of solving the issue and I am sure this will work..may be I have forgot **;** at the end. I am not responding because you have downrated.. I am commenting on the way you are treating the someones response

Comment: @Siva In my book, syntax errors/typos aren't enough to warrant a down vote. If an answer is close or contributes to a correct approach, then it's all good. I've edited your answer and fixed the syntax but the small amount of code you do have doesn't make a whole lot of sense as it stands and *will not work*. In fact, the answer will always be 0. You're checking a record-level field and then overwriting the 'a' variable over and over again with a report-level sum.

Comment: @Ryan...no problem no need of any explanation... Actually I felt bad by seeing words `overly complicated` I can have my own solution. if there is any mistake I  I accept it no hard feelings... everyone are trying to solve issues.. lets not elaborate it